# No messages are output from the second thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have 2 threads:

```
//Second Thread 
private class Init implements Runnable {

 public void run() {
  setTextMessage("Initialization");
  //Perform actions
 }

}
 //First Thread 
 private class Download implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
   setTextMessage("Downloading");
   //Perform actions
   Thread thread = new Thread(new Init());
   thread.start();

 }
}
  public void setTextMessage(final String textMessage) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (dialog != null) {
                setDialogMessage(textMessage);
            }
        }
    });
}

 //Add1
protected void setDialogMessage(Dialog dst, String text) {
    if (dst != null) {
        TextView progressTextDetails = (TextView) dst.findViewById(R.id.progressTextDetails);
        progressTextDetails.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Ideally, after starting the second thread, I see "Initialization" instead "Downloading" on screen and the actions defined in the second thread are performed. But sometimes the message on the screen does not change. Although the actions defined in the second thread are started. The method setTextMessage is called in the second thread, but the text in the UI thread does not change. Why?

Comment: Are you trying first to show Initialization and then Downloading? or is it the other way around?

Comment: First in the main thread (activity) I start the Download

Comment: It will be good if you paste your whole code or `setDialogMessage` method's defination in question's edit..

Comment: Please see Add1

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and when you start **Second Thread** the Second Thread starts and in Second thread you have write code to start **First Thread**.

The First Thread starts so quick so you will be unable to see **Downloading** text and the **Initialization** appears suddenly.

Try to use `Log.e("TAG", "Downloading);` in your Second Thread so you will get know what actually happens.

Comment: I see Downloading always. But sometimes I'm not see Initialization (Downloading stay) on screen. In logs all looks like OK.

Comment: It means **your UI hangs** because there are two different thread your are using and from both you are accessing same **Dialog**. try to dismiss first and then start again your Dialog.  or use two separate dialog for each thread. Hope it will help you.